# Python/Django - Changing Model's attribute from "CharField" to "ForeignKey" fails migrations and everything on "unknown column XXX_id"

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, migration, migrate

Say I had the following model:

```
class greatModel(models.Model):
    attribute = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

and life was good. But then another dev tells me "hey, I actually have a whole model called `attribute` in another app `HIS_APP` on this project! Just make a ForeignKey. Sounds great, so I do:

```
class greatModel(models.Model):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey('HIS_APP.attribute', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but now EVERYTHING I do with this model including migrations will fail on:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'attribute_id' in 'where clause'")
```

Any idea where I might be going wrong? I've tried dropping/remaking the model/table but that was of no use.

Comment: Where is the code? [mcve]